# RSpec: Undefined method 'max' for 4:fixnum

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec

The spec:

```
# spec/row_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

module Mastermind
  describe Row do

    context "#initialize" do
      it "has four elements by default" do
        row = Row.new
        expect(row.values.size).to eq 4
      end

      it "can only go up to 6" do
        row = Row.new
        expect(row.values.max).to be <= 6
      end
    end

  end
end
```

The code:

```
# lib/mastermind/row.rb
module Mastermind
  class Row
    attr_accessor :values
    def initialize (values=random_row)
      @values = values
    end

    def random_row
      4.times {random||=[] << rand(1..6)}
    end

  end
end
```

Row is supposed to be a row for a game of mastermind, with four random values between 1 and 6, and this test is supposed to make sure it is functioning properly. It looks like values is returning an int instead of an array. Why?

How would I troubleshoot this on my own? I tried to make something simple to see exactly what was happening with values by appending

```
row = Row.new
puts row.values
```

to my row.rb, but I just get an uninitialized constant error. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem (`random_row`):

```
[1] pry(main)> 4.times {random||=[] << rand(1..6)}
=> 4
```

`times` returns the value.  You want something like this:

```
[2] pry(main)> 4.times.map { rand(1..6) }
=> [6, 5, 3, 6]
```

Your other issue is because you didn't specify the module, `Row` doesn't exist, `Mastermind::Row` does.

```
[4] pry(main)> row = Mastermind::Row.new
=> #<Mastermind::Row:0x00000101c593e0 @values=4>
[5] pry(main)> row.values
=> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `#random_row` will return `4` (the return value of `Fixnum#times` is `self`), which means that when you initialize the `Row`, `@values` is set to `4`.

You probably want something like:

```
def random_row
  Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
end
```

Comment: Or it can be just: `(1..6).to_a.sample(4)`